# Mp4 files generated from FFMPEG can not be trimmed on quick time player

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to generate mp4 file while recording the screen on a Linux machine.
I am using Spawn with nodeJs:

```html
const transcodeStreamToOutput = spawn('ffmpeg',[
    '-hide_banner',
    '-loglevel', 'error',
    // disable interaction via stdin
    '-nostdin',
    // screen image size
    '-s', `${BROWSER_SCREEN_WIDTH}x${BROWSER_SCREEN_HEIGHT}`,
    // video frame rate
    '-r', `${VIDEO_FRAMERATE}`,
    // hides the mouse cursor from the resulting video
    '-draw_mouse', '0',
    // grab the x11 display as video input
    '-f', 'x11grab',
        '-i', `${DISPLAY}`,
    // grab pulse as audio input
    '-f', 'pulse',
        '-ac', '2',
        '-i', 'default',
    // codec video with libx264
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
        '-profile:v', 'main',
        '-preset', 'veryfast',
        '-x264opts', 'nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut',
        '-minrate', `${VIDEO_BITRATE}`,
        '-maxrate', `${VIDEO_BITRATE}`,
        '-g', `${VIDEO_GOP}`,
    // apply a fixed delay to the audio stream in order to synchronize it with the video stream
    '-filter_complex', 'adelay=delays=1000|1000',
    // codec audio with aac
    '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-b:a', `${AUDIO_BITRATE}`,
        '-ac', `${AUDIO_CHANNELS}`,
        '-ar', `${AUDIO_SAMPLERATE}`,
    // adjust fragmentation to prevent seeking(resolve issue: muxer does not support non seekable output)
    '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
    // set output format to mp4 and output file to stdout
    '-f', 'mp4', '-'
    ]
);
```

The file opens normally on Mac using quick time player but my problem is that it is not editable.
The trim option is disabled on QuickTime player.

Comment: QT probably wants a regular MP4: `ffmpeg -i captured.mp4 -c copy new.mp4`

Comment: The output file to stdout is an mp4 file and I was able to play it on QT,but I need to  trim it and the trim option is disabled on QT.

Comment: Your node output is a fragmented MP4 which has a slightly different structure than a regular MP4. QT may be picky about that.

Comment: I am trying to execute another ffmpeg on the captured input ,but the issue is that I am not able to pass the captured file to the second cmd just like you have mentioned in your comment.